# C programming : Struct array construction while reading a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have a question, and some troubles. I must read a file text with some values. The file looks like this:

```
104 Olympus FE200   244.90
226 JVC MG155   944.20
342 Pentax  OPTIOA20 344
509 Canon   SELPHYES1   299.20
974 Canon   IXUS800IS   444.50
.
.
.

344     Canon   EOS500D   500
```

The different strings are separated by a "\t".

I have to write a function that reads all this and creates me a array of structs defined by:

```
struct product{
int id;
char constructor[MAX_SIZE];
char product_name[MAX_SIZE];
double price;
};
```

I actually can read the file, but it's getting hard with the struct and tab of structs. Any idea?

Comment: Too general question. What is your problem, you can not find a tab, create a struct or an array of structs?

Comment: also, how do you suggest you know where a product name starts and ends?

Comment: actually the product is define as follows:
ID"\t"Constructor"\t"Name"\t"Price
my difficulty is to actually get the values and convert them into integers, doubles in order to create my array of struct Products.

Comment: @DoryZidon: It's delimited by tabs.

Comment: what's wrong with `scanf("%d %s %s %lf", &p.id, p.constructor, p.product_name, &p.price);` ?

Comment: @Elazar: `%s` reads up to any whitespace character. It will stop at a space, which is undesirable; it needs to stop only at a tab or a newline. Rather than `%s`, you'd need to use `%[^\t\n]`.

Comment: @icktoofay who said that?

Comment: @icktoofay +1 for the `%[^\t\n]` syntax.

Comment: @Elazar: The question said it: “the different strings are separated by `\t`.” Looking at the data, it is clear that stopping at a space would not work: there is one example of a `constructor` with a space in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scanf()`:

```
struct product p;
scanf("%d %s %s %lf", &p.id, p.constructor, p.product_name, &p.price);
```

If spaces are a problem, use `%[^\t\n]` instead of `%s`, as suggested by @icktoofay.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers!

The fact is that I am facing an other problem.

Comment: @user2446049 which is... ?

Comment: Actually none, It was about creating a struct called stock, wich would be a tab of products, but I can use directly a tab of products instead of defining another struct.